# Plot random walk in python

Tags: python

I produce the y coordinates of a random walk using the following code.

```
from random import *
n = 10
length = 100*n

def ncount(vector):
    return sum(vector)
randBinList = lambda n: [randint(0,1) for b in xrange(1,n+1)]

vector = randBinList(length)

ycoords = [ncount(vector[i:i+n-1]) for i in xrange(length-n+1)]
xcoords = range(length-n+1)
```

How can I plot this random walk in 2d?

Comment: Using a plotting library? `matplotlib` for instance? Although, you'd normally use that in conjuction with `numpy` or something when doing numerical analysis...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pylab import *

ycoords = [ncount(vector[i:i+n-1]) for i in xrange(length-n+1)]
xcoords = range(length-n+1)

plot(xcoords,ycoords)

show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the very first example given at http://matplotlib.org/users/screenshots.html This should help you to get started:

```
plot(x, y)
```

is "about at simple as it gets"..